# Jquery : Attribute Start With for current element

Tags: jquery, jquery-attributes

Attribute "Start With" in jquery is very simple, but i have a problem
How use this attribute for current element?
As example i tried:

```
$('this[id^= "PostTypes"]')
```

AND

```
$(this[id^= "PostTypes"])
```

But nothing want works.

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: @ArunPJohny i try to get id of current element and if it stat with "PostTypes" make some changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
 $('[id^= "PostTypes"]', this); // if you want to find the elements that are descendants of this.
```

Or if you want to check if the current element is a match then you can use [.is(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/is/#is-selector):

```
$(this).is('[id^= "PostTypes"]'); //Check if this element is havind the id startswith PostTypes.
```

Example:

```
if($(this).is('[id^= "PostTypes"]')){
   //Current element starts with id PostTypes, do something with it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$(this).filter('[id^= "PostTypes"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
$('[id^="PostTypes"]', this)
```